# Pass Multiple Guid Values To Same Paramater

Tags: api, wcf

I want to send a list of guid to a post method ,as an url parameter and not in a  json object :

```
http://localhost:19116/CustomerManagement.svc/AddServiceContract?s=[44A05EC5-DA1E-4D71-9F23-7194E2996BAE,44A05EC5-DA1E-4D71-9F23-7194E2996BAE]
```

the template i used is like that

```
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, UriTemplate = "AddServiceContract?s={alertGroupId}")]

    Guid AddServiceContract(Guid[] alertGroupId,AssetContractAddRequestApi request);
```

But that return me an error ,is that possible if yes what i am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching for a solution , i found that there's no standard as it's described [here](https://hugomartins.io/essays/2021/02/how-to-pass-multiple-values-to-http-query-parameter/)

so i just used a parameter as string (string alertGroupId) ? and from postman  i used this call :

```
http://localhost:19116/CustomerManagement.svc/AddServiceContract?alertGroupId=5B7DD5F5-79A2-405E-A824-0B7201018C14&alertGroupId=1717B90C-348B-4D85-9608-69288180ED96&alertGroupId=44A05EC5-DA1E-4D71-9F23-7194E2996BAE
```

in csharp, you get a comma separated string *alertGroupId* , that you can split